# Overriding ConfigurableSwatches Helper 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to override ConfigurableSwatches within Magento 1.9.1

I have config file at /app/etc/modules/Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>    
        </Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I have created a folder for files: /app/code/local/Vlad/ConfigurableSwatches/ 
Folder has two more folders: "Helper" and "etc"

"etc" folder has Config.xml file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches>
        </modules>

        <global>
           <helpers>
              <tag>
                  <rewrite>
                      <data>Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productimg</data>
                 </rewrite>
              </tag>
           </helpers>
        </global>
  </config>
```

"Helper" folder has a file "Productimg.php" with following data:

```
class Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productimg extends Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productimg
{ 
    public function getSwatchUrl($product, $value, $width = self::SWATCH_DEFAULT_WIDTH,
         $height = self::SWATCH_DEFAULT_HEIGHT, &$swatchType, $fallbackFileExt = null
    ) { 
        echo 1; exit; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue at wrong calling of *helper  prefix*   at ***config.xml***

it should be  `configurableswatches`  from  `tag`.

As per as ,magento  `configurableswatches`is  helper  prefix  *class  type  which define at*

***See  at config.xml of Mage_ConfigurableSwatches Module:***

```
    <global>
....
    <helpers> 
            <configurableswatches><!--  this  is called  Mage_ConfigurableSwatches module  helper prefix -->
                <class>Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper</class>
            </configurableswatches>
        </helpers>
    </global>
```

But you have ***called Mage_Tag*** module  ***helper  prefix***.

> ```
>         <global>
> ....
>   <helpers> 
>             <tag><!--  this  is called  Mage_Tag module  helper prefix -->
>                 <class>Mage_Tag_Helper</class>
>             </tag>
>         </helpers>
>   ....
>     </global>
> ```

Also there are issue  `<data>`  tag should be `<productimg>`

**You need to change**

```
       <helpers>
          <tag>
              <rewrite>
                  <data>Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productimg</data>
             </rewrite>
          </tag>
       </helpers>
```

to

```
<helpers>
<configurableswatches><!-- change here -->
  <rewrite>
      <productimg>Vlad_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productimg</productimg>
 </rewrite>
</configurableswatches><!-- change here -->
</helpers>
```

Comment: Ah finally.. it worked now, i was expecting change to happen straight away, but it seem to have taken a minute even those cache is switched on inside magento.